# Blender 2.83.5 - disable right click -> move

Tags: vertices

I just installed 2.83.5 and I am setting things up

I just cannot find where to disable 'right-click' -> moves object

**I don't want objects to be move when I select them with the right button**

thanks

Comment: Wait. Right click moves objects? Did you load the default settings or the right-click selection settings? Normally the right click opens a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

in preferences
input
untick releases confirm

but the way it feels is not like previous versions, I just hate 2.8 so far